# Is there a way to create a binary tree in Erlang using processes?

Tags: functional-programming, tree, erlang, binary-tree, erlang-supervisor

I am trying to create a binary tree using processes.

```
-module(binarytree).

-export([start/1, loop/2]).

start(N) ->
    P = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N, self(), self(), self()]),
    P ! create_nodes,
    receive
    end.

loop(0, _, _, _) ->
    done;

loop(N, Root, LeftNode, RightNode) ->
    receive
        create_nodes ->
            MyPid = self(),
            LeftNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, ???, ???]),
            RightNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, ???, ???]),
            LeftNode ! create_nodes,
            RightNode ! create_nodes;
        _ ->
            ok
    end,
    loop(N, Root, LeftNode, RightNode).
```

Without `LeftNode` and `RightNode` I am creating tree structure successfully, but I want to save `LeftNode` and `RightNode` in loop's state. What should I pass in function arguments when creating nodes?

**Update:
Thanks to Nalin Ranjan.** Change these lines:

```
MyPid = self(),
LeftNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, ???, ???]),
RightNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, ???, ???]),
LeftNode ! create_nodes,
RightNode ! create_nodes;
```

To:

```
MyPid = self(),
NewLeftNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, "", ""]),
NewRightNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, "", ""]),
NewLeftNode ! create_nodes,
NewRightNode ! create_nodes,
loop(N, Root, NewLeftNode, NewRightNode);
```

Comment: First of all, your code will crash on the following lines:-

```
...
LeftNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, ???, ???]),
RightNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, ???, ???]),
...
```

Even if you can manage to compile it after substituting ???(s)...

Comment: Yes, if I pass 4 arguments in loop state, it is crashing. But, if I change arguments to only N and Parent, code compiles and processes are created like tree. My problem is that I can't pass LeftNode and RightNode as arguments, because they are not created yet.

Comment: But while creating a child(Left or right), you want to save the child within the state of the child itself ??

Comment: Ok, if I don't save childs in state, then how one node will know his childs pids ?

Comment: When a node is created, it may not have any children. So, we must first provision for creating a node with empty left and right.

Comment: For example, if we look at the following line from the code above...

P = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N, self(), self(), self()]),

... It says, create a root whose left and right node is the root itself. At least, by reading at it, that is what I am able to infer.

Comment: For example, If I say... `LeftNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N, self(), self(), self()])`... it will spawn a process like you say, but previous process, spawned in `start` function wouldn't know that `LeftNode` is his child. Can you provide an example with working code or pseudo code?

Comment: can you try something like following...

```
loop(N, Root, LeftNode, RightNode) ->
    receive
        create_nodes ->
            MyPid = self(),
            NewLeftNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, "empty-child-node", "empty-child-node"),
            NewRightNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, "empty-child-node", "empty-child-node"]),
            NewLeftNode ! create_nodes,
            NewRightNode ! create_nodes,
     loop(N, Root, NewLeftNode, NewRightNode);
        _ ->
            ok
    end,
    loop(N, Root, LeftNode, RightNode).

```

Comment: Oh, now I understand. It is fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loop(N, Root, LeftNode, RightNode) -> 
 receive 
  create_nodes -> 
    MyPid = self(),
    NewLeftNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, "empty-child-node", "empty-child-node"),
    NewRightNode = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [N-1, MyPid, "empty-child-node", "empty-child-node"]), 
    NewLeftNode ! create_nodes, 
    NewRightNode ! create_nodes, 
    loop(N, Root, NewLeftNode, NewRightNode); 

  _ -> ok 
end, 
loop(N, Root, LeftNode, RightNode).
```

Try this one out.

Comment: Yes, this works. I updated my first post and will mark your answer as acceppted.